# Import Named Lotus123 spreadsheet to MS Access

Tags: vba, lotus

I'm in the process of moving all the Lotus sheets a company has to a SQL Server and I am using MS Access tables as an intermediary.
This code has been working fine for sheets that are not named but I've come across about 2300 or so sheets where it's named numb. There are too many files for me to manually change them all.

The error I am getting is: 
Run-Time error '-2147217865(80040e37)':
The Microsoft Jet Database engine could not find the object "numb:A1..numb:A8000". Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Found this site but that hasn't provided the [answer](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/query-a-lotus-123-file.65372/page-2)

I've seen different options for getting the destination right on an ADOB call ("SELECT * FROM [numb:A1..numb:A8000];" or ("SELECT * FROM [numb$:A1..numb$:A8000];") and those haven't worked.

Here is the functioning code when the sheet isn't named:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim LotusCn As Object
Dim rsLotus As Object
'Read WK3 Lotus files
    repcode = rs![Code]
    Directory = rs![Directory]
    Directory = Directory & "NUMDATM.WK3"
    Set LotusCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsLotus = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    'This creates the objects for the lotus connctions
    'below the connection string

   LotusCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & Directory & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Lotus WK3;Persist Security Info=False"
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM  [A1..A8000];" 'The SQL to pick the right sections of the lotus file. Picks the Latest Available Date
    rsLotus.Open strSQL, LotusCn, adOpenStatic  '<<< ***Error occurs here***
    If Not (rsLotus.EOF And rsLotus.BOF) Then
        FindRecordCount = rsLotus.RecordCount
        rsLotus.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsLotus.EOF = True
            Debug.Print rsLotus.Fields(0).Value
            If Len(rsLotus.Fields(0).Value) > 0 Then
                rst.AddNew
                    rst!RegNo = rsLotus.Fields(0).Value
                rst.Update
            End If
        rsLotus.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    LotusCn.Close
    strSQL = ""
    Set rsLotus = Nothing
    Set LotusCn = Nothing
```

Does anyone know how to get named spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly how in Lotus but this was in Excel

```
Set oRs = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables) 'get the name of the sheet in Excel
                oRs.MoveFirst
                With oRs
                    While Not .EOF

                        If .fields("TABLE_TYPE") = "TABLE" Then
                            Debug.Print .fields("TABLE_NAME")

                            If VBA.Len(.fields("TABLE_NAME")) = 9 Then
                                WSnameTBL = .fields("TABLE_NAME")

                            Else
                            End If

                          '  WSnameTBL = VBA.Replace(WSnameTBL, "$", "", 1, , vbTextCompare)
                        End If
                    .MoveNext
                    Wend
                End With
```